# json files and called features not found in jenkins (with Karate Framework)

Tags: jenkins, karate

---

In my feature I have:
`* def bar = read('classpath:features/xxx/foo.json')`

But when I run tests in Jenkins, I have an error:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: read('classpath:features/xxx/foo.json')
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:423)
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:394)
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:316)
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:194)
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:656)
>   at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:587)
>   at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:265)
>   at ✽.* def u = read('classpath:features/xxx/foo.json')(features/XXX/calling.feature:7)
> Caused by: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateFileNotFoundException: file not
> ```
>
> found: features/xxx/foo.json, classpath: true
>         at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.readFileAsString(FileUtils.java:104)
>         at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:80)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$8$15A$\^eval_.L:1(:3)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:639)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.call(ScriptObjectMirror.java:117)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$19$\^eval_.:program(:1)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
>         at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
>         at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
>         at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:419)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:394)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:316)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:194)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:656)
>         at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:587)
>         at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:265)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
>         at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
>         at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
>         at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberUtils.runStep(CucumberUtils.java:136)
>         at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntime.runStep(KarateRuntime.java:78)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
>         at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
>         at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.lambda$parallel$0(CucumberRunner.java:84)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (it severely lacks details), everything works fine on your local machine, but does not work when running on Jenkins.

Don't you have a little bit more stack trace to provide ?

There could be so many possible reasons. Maybe on Jenkins, non-Java files are not being copied correctly to `target/test-classes`. Check whether the `pom.xml` on Jenkins is not behaving differently for example because of a Maven profile. You should work with your Jenkins admin / CI team to solve this.

Comment: please read the doc on directory structure. also check if the features are being copied to `target/classes` or `target/test-classes` by gradle. all the very best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159244/discussion-between-nirind-and-peter-thomas).

Comment: is there any way to put 'classpath:foo/bar/' in one place and to call it from that place? in order to have only one place to write or update directory names, to avoid mistakes. When you put the same directory names in several features, the risk to make case mistakes is high. Thanks for you tips

Comment: of course. just make this as a variable in `karate-config.js` and then use it in all your tests, you can use expressions in `read` for e.g. `read(myPathPrefix + 'called.feature')`

Comment: @nirind Can you please elaborate, what fixed worked for you? What was the exact issue? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you help me to find out the fix which worked in this case? I got the exact issue while running test cases in Jenkin. Nirind seems not much active here.  I have checked the target/test-classes folder directory, files are there. I changed the file case to lowercase also but that also didn't work.

Comment: @deepakmathpal what do you suggest I do :) only thing I can suggest extra is follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @deepakmathpal check all capital and tiny letters of file names or any other references that you call from jenkins. It is case sensible. ex: in your runner> check cases in feature names, paths. It should be exactly the same in jenkins and your runner

Comment: @nirind this is my path in feature file: read('classpath:apiTest/testData/graphqlflattensmoke.graphql'). The file name(graphqlflattensmoke),I have already changed to lowercase in both location, feature as well as in folders.

Comment: @deepakmathpal did you check your runner: @CucumberOptions(features = {"classpath:features/xxxx/"})